# code for codeigniter for joining same table with AS

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have below sql code for selecting data from table,
I have difficulty in writing code in codeigniter framework,
Can someone help me on this?
This code runs on same table ec_user.

I don't know how to use AS in codeigniter,

```
SELECT EMP.`user_id`,EMP.`user_firstname`,EMP.`user_lastname`, MGR.`user_firstname` AS Managerfirstname, MGR.`user_lastname` AS Managerlastname FROM ec_user AS MGR JOIN ec_user AS EMP ON MGR.`user_id` = EMP.`manager_id`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code use your code accordingly.

```
$query = $this->db->select('EMP.`user_id`,EMP.`user_firstname`,EMP.`user_lastname`, MGR.`user_firstname` AS Managerfirstname, MGR.`user_lastname` AS Managerlastname')
                    ->from('ec_user AS MGR')
                    ->join('ec_user AS EMP', 'MGR.`user_id` = EMP.`manager_id`');
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, i was already tried with this, but i was looking as complete pattern of CI of select and join.

Comment: Thanks it worked, here if final code,   --------------    $this->db->select('EMP.user_id, EMP.user_firstname, EMP.user_lastname, EMP.user_email, EMP.employee_id,EMP.user_currency,MGR.user_firstname AS manager_firstname, MGR.user_lastname AS manager_lastname');
                    $this->db->from('ec_user AS MGR');
                    $this->db->join('ec_user AS EMP', 'MGR.user_id = EMP.manager_id');
     return $this->db->get()->result_array();